# Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity in Eclipse, but not in IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, kotlin

I want to access the values of a Java enum in my Kotlin code:

```
MyEnumClass.values().forEach {
    doSomething(it)
}
```

This works fine in IntelliJ, however Eclipse (oxygen) with Kotlin-Plugin (0.8.2) complains:

> Multiple markers at this line - Overload resolution ambiguity: public
>   open fun values(): Array! defined in my.package.MyEnumClass public
>   final fun values(): Array defined in my.package.MyEnumClass - Cannot
>   choose among the following candidates without completing type
>   inference: @HidesMembers public inline fun Iterable.forEach(action:
>   (???) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections @HidesMembers
>   public inline fun Map.forEach(action: (Map.Entry) -> Unit): Unit
>   defined in kotlin.collections

The autocomplete suggestions in eclipse show me `Array<MyEnumClass>` and `Array<(out) MyEnumClass!>!` as available return types for `values()`. The latter would however not show in IntelliJ's autocomplete, thus no ambiguity there.

Comment: I don't have Eclipse, but does [enumValues](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/enum-values.html) get around this issue? `enumValues<MyEnumClass>().forEach { doSomething(it) }`

Comment: Yes, this would fix it. Thank you!

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KE-331